# Load laravel model where relationship has condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I was wondering how I could load all models of a type where a specific conditions is met.
Lets take the following example setup.
I have 2 eloquent models, `House` and `Rental`. A `House` has a `hasMany` relationship to the `Rental`.

```
public function rentals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rental::class);
}
```

The Rental class has a `review` column which can have the following values: `positive` or `negative`.

Now I'd like to "override" the default query builder which can be done using:

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true) {
    return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted);
}
```

Note: this does not change the default behaviour.

I'd like to know how I can change the default `House` query to only return the `House` instances which have at least any arbitrary number (`x`) `Rentals` with a `review` equal to `positive`.

So `House::all()` should only return `Houses` with at least `x` `positive` `Rentals`.

Bonuspoints if you can also explain how to add another function which can be used to query all `Houses`

My question seems to have a lot in common with the `softDeletes` trait of Laravel, `softDeletes` models only query models where the `deleted_at` column is non null. The bonus part of my question can be seen as the `::withTrashed()` option on a query.
The application is build on Laravel 5.4.

Comment: In your `House::all()` example, where is the value of `x` determined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to use `whereHas` to load the houses that meet certain criteria.

```
$houses = House::whereHas('rentals', function($q) {
    $q->where('review', 'positive');
}, '>=', $x)->get();
```

Here, `$x` is the number of positive reviews a house must have before it shows up.

It's pretty simple so I'm not sure if it's still a candidate for adding this condition as default since you also want to be able to remove the default too at times.  Perhaps the better solution is to drop this in a function in the `House` model which you can re-use and not worry about having it work by default.

Comment: This already works beautifully, I requested the default implementation because the project is getting fairly big and the `positive` `rentals` is used in over 90% of the cases, I think the code is clearer and better readable if this would be the default way of handeling it. Although adding a scope for the house which implements this code also works pretty well.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `whereHas` doesn't eager load so unless you also add a `with('rentals')` to this, you will be facing the 1+n problem, assuming you are trying to loop through the `rentals` for each house.